# Angular2, subscribe property on EventEmitter not existing?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, event-handling

My `app.component` contains the `<nav>` of the website, which uses `[routerLink]` to go to the different pages. It imports each of the pages' components. One of the pages is a login page. If the user is not logged in, I want the navigation to say Login- if the user is, Logout.

In `app.component`:

```
my_userO : userO = undefined;

constructor (private my_userS:userS){
    my_userS.userChanged.suscribe(temp => this.updateNav());

updateNav(){ 
    this.my_userO = this.my_userS.getUser(); 
}

logOut(){
    this.my_userS.setUser(undefined);
}
```

and in its template:

```
<li><a *ngIf="!my_userO" [routerLink]="['LoginPage']">Login</a></li>
<li><a *ngIf="my_userO" [routerLink]="['HomePage']"(click)="logOut()">Logout</a></li>
```

`userS` is a global service (it is bootstrapped in `main.ts` and not added as a provider in any of the components I am using it in) I have that looks like this:

```
public userChanged: EventEmitter<{}>
currentUser : userO = undefined;

constructor(private http:Http){
    this.userChanged = new EventEmitter();
}

getLogin(username: string, password: string): Promise<userO>{
    return this.http.get(this.getLoginUrl+username).toPromise().then(response => response.json().data).catch(this.handleError);
}

getUser(){
    return this.currentUser;
}

setUser(x_userO: userO){
    this.currentUser = x_userO;
    this.userChanged.emit(undefined);
}
```

In the login page, I just run `getLogin` then `setUser` with what the former returned.

My problem is that I get the error "Property suscribe does not exist on type EventEmitter<{}>".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a typo

Use `subscribe`, not `suscribe`

I don't have enough reputation to answer Colum below but that's totally incorrect.

1. `emit()` returns void
2. `EventEmitter` extends (inherits) `Subject` which is an observable and an observer.

   ```
   export declare class EventEmitter<T> extends Subject<T>
   ```

an `EventEmitter` is an rxjs Subject with some modifications, most notably it does not use next() to send a value down the stream but uses emit().
It also allows setting an async logic where the emit will be async.

Comment: Thanks... sorry, I have no idea why it wasn't working since I was following someone else's example, and then the angular.io doc showed a subscribe property... I need to get more sleep haha. It compiles now, but I can't test it until later.

Comment: ugh... dat facepalm when I have been not understanding why suscribe is not defined for at least half an hour...

Comment: the comment about emit() saved my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

using vscode, auto complete added this line:

> import { EventEmitter } from '**events**';

i had to change it to the following to resolve this.:

> import { EventEmitter } from '**@angular/core**';

Comment: Vscode is still doing the same in 2021... LOL :)

Comment: and the same in 2022…

Comment: it auto completes mine with `stream`

Answer (score 12):

check for the import of EventEmitter

it should be `import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have a subscribe method as it does not return an observable.

The `emit()` method of `EventEmitter` does however return an observable so you need to create an input which is connected to the event that is emitted. 
You can then subscribe to this.

Take a look at this: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/unit-testing-eventemitter-in-angular-2.0