# Property 'custom' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter<any>'

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ionic3

I'm using ionic 3, and I have a **part** component and a **parts** page

**Parts.html page:**

```
<ion-row> 
   <part [part]="part"></part>
</ion-row>
```

The **part** variable of parts.html is this json:

[image]

**Part.ts component:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Input, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

export class PartComponent {
    @Input() part = new EventEmitter<any>();

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.setInitialValues();
    }
    ngOnChanges(){
        this.setInitialValues();
    }

    setInitialValues() {
      console.log(this.part);
      if (this.part) {

        if (this.part.hasOwnProperty('parts') && this.part.parts.length != 0) {
          this.hasParts = true;
        }
        this.getPartQuestionnaire(this.part.id);
      }
    }
```

**I'm getting this errors when i'm building the ionic app:**

Property 'parts' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter'.

> L81:        if (this.part.hasOwnProperty('parts') &&
>   this.part.parts.length != 0) {
>
> L82:          this.hasParts = true;

Property **'id'** does not exist on type 'EventEmitter'.

> L84:  this.getPartQuestionnaire(this.part.id);

When I comment this lines of part.ts and show in console the variable part, I get the foow image representation, where the first 2 calls appear null, but after it load the part values:

[image]

How can I solve this error when I try to build the app?

I'm building with `ionic cordova run browser`

Comment: you probably have import incorrect EventEmitter. related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249155/angular2-subscribe-property-on-eventemitter-not-existing

Comment: i updated here with the import, I've saw this related, but i couldn't resolve with it @MadhawaPriyashantha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line

**From**

```
 @Input() part = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

**To**

```
@Input() part : any;
```

Answer (score 1):

There multiple things wrong in your code example.

1.@Input is used to accept the data from a parent component whereas we use 
EventEmitter with the @Output decorator. You have mixed them.

2.when you have written:

```
@Input() part = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

it means the variable **part** is of type **EventEmitter** now and not type **Part**.

To make it work either change the type of part as @Sajeetharan has suggested or like this:

```
@input Part: IPart; // IPart is an interface which matches the structure of your data.
@Output myOutput = new EventEmitter<any>();
```